# Disable the topViewController

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

Is it possible to disable the topViewController when the slidingViewController is open? I'm using ECSlidingViewController version ~1.3 and when I expose the menu the topViewController isn't touchable. However, in a new project I am using the latest version (2.0.2) of ECSlidingViewController and when I expose the menu the topViewController is still touchable. I'd like to disable the top view when it's slid off to the side. It doesn't make sense to allow the user to touch anything other than the hamburger menu in this situation because only a small portion is visible.

I've been looking, unsuccessfully, for a way to disable the view but no such luck so far. I even tried to setting the topViewController.view.touchesEnabled property to NO when the hamburger menu is touched but for some reason this also disables the hamburger menu so you can only close the menu by using the gesture.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does ECSlidindViewController use gestures? If so you should be able to set the gestures enabled property to NO when the topViewController is open.